# UISearchController.isActive is showing false while editing in searchbar?

Tags: ios, swift3, uicollectionview, uisearchcontroller, uisearchresultscontroller

I have added a search bar above a collection view controller. On activating the search controller the **UISearchcontroller.isActive** is returning "**true**" but while editing it's returning "**false**". But in tableview controller the same implementation working fine. Can anyone explain please what is the reason and how to solve it?

```
var resultSearchController = UISearchController()

func viewdidLoad() {
self.resultSearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
self.resultSearchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
self.resultSearchController.searchBar.delegate = self
self.definesPresentationContext = true
self.resultSearchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
self.resultSearchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search for Stores"
self.resultSearchController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyle.prominent
self.resultSearchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
collectionView?.delegate = self
collectionView?.dataSource = self
}

func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
   print(self.resultSearchController.isActive)
}
```

Comment: can you post your code?

Answer (score 0):

make sure that in both cases your instance variable contains the same `UISearchcontroller` Object. By printing the object address in both cases.